# Index and sum to calculate fuel consumption

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to calculate fuel consumptions for golf course machinery which I have filtered into a sheet below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8G-i9WeSkBE_fmL911_750O29AvtRU0GytLP-1gi_w/edit?usp=sharing

I have manually calculated the consumption for machine 7500 #2, however I'm stuck in terms of creating a formula which will essentially do the same in column H and calculate for all machines listed in column B.

I'd imagine there is some indexing required but I'm battling to reference the last date in a range for a specific machine and then do the calc.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(D2:D/(E2:E-VLOOKUP(
 B2:B&COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))-1, {
 B2:B&COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)), E2:E}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, a solution and an education for me!

Comment: Next to player0s reply, can you hit the checkbox to accept the answer?

Comment: @tomf fyi, the OP won't get your comment coz you did not tag him while commenting on my answer. he would get it without taging him if the comment is under his question... just saying...

Comment: I guess that makes sense.:)